# Past modals and "like"

Tags: verbs, past-tense, modal-verbs

I need to rewrite a sentence by using the past modals.

"Luke's given that watch away to a friend" (standard sentence)
"Clearly he didn't like it then". (the sentence I have to rewrite with a modal verb)

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What are some other examples from your textbook/homework? That will give us a better idea of what you need.

Answer (score 2):

"He must not have liked it then."

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the sentence as it stands, but it could be:

'He must not have liked it then'.

Equally any of the following would be grammatical:

'he could not have...', 'he will not have...', 'he may not have...' etc.